# "The same applies for time" or "The same applies to time"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am wondering whether it is legitimate to use both "The same applies for time" and "The same applies to time" in the sense of "The same is true for time".

I would be grateful for your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please give more context for this sentence? To what does "the same" refer?

Comment: For example, "In the case of X value, the shape of the line indicates that there is a certain point at which the process output reaches maximum value. The same applies for time."